# IntelliJ IDEA: tool window shortcuts (numbers) are missing

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Bottom bar shortcuts not shown. But I can see it while hovering on particular tab.
[image: missing shortcuts]

In previous versions it was always shown. Is there any way to show shortcuts all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | **Show tool window numbers**.

[image: Show tool window numbers]